# Update fields on the fly on odoo10 wizard

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, wizard

I have a wizard and a button Calculate which has this at the end of the 
function:

```
return {
        "type": "set_scrollTop",
    }
```

When the button Calculate is clicked, it is printing the correct values,
but self.margin (the field that needs to be updated) is not updated. It just
puts 0 inside (its a float field).

Did you have this problem and know how to resolve it?

Comment: More detail please

Comment: its like this in short:
i click a button and a wizard opens and i have the active_id from the context and
i prefil all the required fields.
Then i have a button on wizard itself named CALCULATE which is setting the 
fields as : self.margin = some_value
Now all is correct but the fields on the wizard (self.margin) is not updated on 
the view of the wizard.